# how to implement below data structure in java using collection framework

Tags: java, collections

I have below data structure like this

```
Country,StateID1 where StateID1 contains "City1","City2","City3" etc
Country,StateID2 where StateID2 contains "City1","City2","City3" etc
```

I know i can't use HashMap to implement above data structure because if i add StateID2 to same Country StateID1 will be replace with StateID2
for eg

```
map.put("1","1111");
map.put("1","2222");
output

 key:value
 1:2222`
```

i am facing hard time to figure out how to do this. I need some support from you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `class` for the same.

```
class YourClass
{
     String country;
     State state;
}

class State
{
    Set<String> cities;
}
```

You can then use this `class` as a data structure. You don't really need to use Collections framework for the same.

**OR**

If you really want to do it using Collections, then you can use a combination of `Country` and `StateId` as the `key`, and the list of cities as the `value` in a `Map`. For ex:

```
String country = "1";
String state = "1";
String separator = "-" // You could use any separator
String key = country + separator + state;
Set<String> cities = new HashSet<String>();
cities.add("1");
cities.add("2");

Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); 
map.put(key, cities);
```

So your `key` would be `1-1` and value would be `12`.

Answer (score 1):

You need some wrapping object for storing your 'state' data. Then you can have a structure like this: `Map<String, List<StateBean>>`. This way you can handle a list of state for every country.
If data are just Strings use `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 1):

`You can have a Map<String, Set<String>>.`

Answer (score 1):

Store the `StationIDs` in an `ArrayList` object and add those object in a `HashMap` using key-value pair .. where key is the Country against the StationId `ArrayList` Object.

```
StateID1 = ["City1","City2"]    // ArrayList
StateID2 = ["City1","City2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could have the map as **Country,ListOfStates**

**ListOfStates** could be a list that contains **StateIds**

Or StateIds as a Map with StateId as key and list of cities as value

Answer (score 0):

Use can Data Structure map < String,vector < String >> , map < class T,vector < class U > >